# Getting invalid context when drawing image in context

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I am designing an interface where a user can scale and rotate an image using gestures and then merge the image with the background image when they are done. I am having issues with merging the rotated image with the background.

```
- (void) donePlacingPicture
{
    UIImage * scaledTopImg = [self.photoImage.image imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:self.photoImage.frame.size];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledTopImg.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, scaledTopImg.size.width * 0.5f, scaledTopImg.size.height  * 0.5f);
    CGFloat angle = atan2(self.photoImage.transform.b, self.photoImage.transform.a);
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, angle);
    [scaledTopImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(- scaledTopImg.size.width * 0.5f, -(scaledTopImg.size.height  * 0.5f), scaledTopImg.size.width, scaledTopImg.size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.MainImage.image.size);
    [self.MainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.MainImage.image.size.width, self.MainImage.image.size.height)];
    [newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.photoImage.frame.origin.x, self.photoImage.frame.origin.y, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height)];
    self.MainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

    self.photoImage.hidden = TRUE;
    self.photoImage = nil;
}
```

This is giving me the following errors

```
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Sometimes this function works and the image be added in its rotated form but the scale will be slightly off and the corners will be cropped and other times nothing will apear and I will get these errors. I believe the error is from

```
[newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.photoImage.frame.origin.x, self.photoImage.frame.origin.y, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height)];
```

causing the image context to be set to nil which throws the errors when

```
self.MainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

is reached. I do not get the errors when either of these lines are commented out.

Does anyone know what the errors mean, know a better way to views when one is rotated, or can point towards a sample project where this is done?

Thanks in advance and this is my first post to stackoverflow. I realize there are multiple questions similar to this one but none of them where very helpful in my situation.